# Error Indicator Active but won't disappear

Tags: java, web, error-handling, vaadin, vaadin-valo-theme

I am writing a web page with Vadding 7. However, I found for some component,  e.g. Button.  If it got a error in background ,it will show Error Indicator !. And it will not disappear even the next click on this button already return successfull result in the same papge. Any way to make it disappear if next action already be success?

Comment: You should handle server side errors in your code and not use the error notification of the components. They are not meant for this. There is the Notification class for informing the user about server errors.